# Why am I getting Xamarin.Essentails.FeatureNotSupportedException only on my Samsung device

Tags: c#, xamarin, samsung-galaxy, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to open a webpage. The specific Code for that is

```cs
Browser.OpenAsync(uri, new BrowserLaunchOptions
{
  LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.External,
});
```

On Virtual Devices both Android and iOS as well as on physical iOS devices and on some Android Devices (like an Android 12 Pixel 5 and an old Motorola API 25) it works just fine. I have, however, one Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android 11, and that is the only device were this crash appears.

I am at my wits end, why it is only that device and because I only have those phones I cannot figure out if it is an Android 11 or Samsung issue, I am hoping someone here knows the cause and solution.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I'll add this comment as it not an answer nor belongs in the question: I fixed it by try/catching and in the catch i put BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred